# htaccess in subfolders for multi-language set-friendly urls in root file instead

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, server

I have domain.com with two language subfolders:

```
domain.com/english 
and 
domain.com/espanol
```

Each one of these subfolders have its own .htaccess file to display seo-friendly urls. So instead of displaying the url like this:

```
domain.com/english/news.php?id=4749
or 
domain.com/espanol/noticias.php?id=5734
```

It displays urls like this:

```
domain.com/english/world/europe/some-date/this-is-the-news-title
or 
domain.com/espanol/mundo/europa/some-date/este-es-un-titulo
```

Depending on the "language" (subfolder) chosen by the visitor.

The truth is that I don't know if it is correct or not to only  apply .htaccess rules to the subfolders and nothing in the root folder (domain.com/) because some articles on Internet says that many servers are not compatible with .htaccess files in subfolders, but for the moment it is working fine.

So I decided to try to delete the .htaccess from the subfolders and just create a singe .htaccess in the root (domain.com/) but It is not working :(

Any idea how to fix it?

Here is the code from the .htaccess in subfolders:

domain.com/english

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ news.php?id=$1
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ news.php?id=$1
```

domain.com/espanol

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ noticias.php?id=$1
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ noticias.php?id=$1
```

in root folder domain.com/ I tried this:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ news.php?id=$1
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ news.php?id=$1
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ noticias.php?id=$1
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ noticias.php?id=$1
```

But it does nto work, nothing is displayed

NOTE: it is not a duplicated because the other questions are not similar or does nto answer my question. Thanks

Comment: Do your URLs contain a trailing slash? Do they contain any slashes beyond the "slug/id"?

Comment: Nope it just looks like this domain.com/english/news.php?id=4749

Comment: But that's not what your existing rules do at all?! You said you have URLs like `/english/this-is-the-news-title`. There is no "numeric ID" in this URL, so would be rewritten to `news.php?id=this-is-the-news-title`. Where does the numeric `4749` come from?

Comment: from MySQL it is the id of the article, every article has its own ID. The problem is not in MySQL but in the htaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ news.php?id=$1
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ news.php?id=$1
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ noticias.php?id=$1
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ noticias.php?id=$1
> ```

By moving the rules into the root `.htaccess` file you now need to take into account the "language" subdirectory in the URL-path. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (1st argument) matches against a URL-path that is relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file.

If you don't take into account the language subdirectory then you have the same regex pattern and two different endpoints - which is impossible to resolve.

However, your existing rules are not doing quite what you are expecting. The 2nd rule, with the trailing slash, is not being used since the preceding rule also includes a slash in the character class and so the request will always be processed by the first rule, not the second. The question then is... what is the canonical URL, with or without a trailing slash? You are trying to allow for both here, but that is detrimental for SEO. If you are expecting erroneous URLs with one or the other then you should externally redirect from one to the other in order to canonicalise the URL.

To resolve your immediate issue with the language subdirectory then you would need to change your rules like this:

**UPDATED**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(english)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ $1/news.php?id=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(espanol)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ $1/noticias.php?id=$2 [L]
```

The language subdirectory is captured and passed through to the *substitution* string in the `$1` backreference (saves repetition). Consequently, the *slug* (or "id") is now contained in the `$2` backreference.

Note also the addition of the `L` flag. There is no need to process additional rules after a rule has been successful.

In light of your comments, I have removed the slash from the regex character class completely.

HOWEVER, this does not rewrite the request from `/english/this-is-the-news-title` to `/english/news.php?id=4749` as would seem to be implied by your question. It rewrites `/english/this-is-the-news-title` to `/english/news.php?id=this-is-the-news-title` - which is then dependent on your PHP application looking up the relevant *id*.

> because some articles on Internet says that many servers are not compatible with .htaccess files in subfolders

That is not true. Do you have a reference? It is usually preferable to have a single `.htaccess` file in the root, but that is not necessarily a requirement.

Comment: I got confused :) does it rewrite /english/news.php?id=4749 to /english/this-is-the-news-title ? because this is what I am looking for, but I will try your solution right now

Comment: It does not worked :( display 404 error

Comment: @thesubfolders Sorry, I missed the language subdirectory from the _substitution_ string! I've updated my answer. "does it rewrite /english/news.php?id=4749 to /english/this-is-the-news-title" - No, it does the complete opposite (and different). You are requesting (ie. linking to in your HTML source) URLs of the form `/english/this-is-the-news-title` which is then internally rewritten to `/english/news.php?id=this-is-the-news-title`. This is the same as what your original directives (in the subdirectory) did, which you say are "working fine".

Comment: I get 404 error

Comment: I think it is because my slugs are saved like this: world/news/europe/2022/10/22/test-news-title so if I click on the article title I go to  domain.com/english/world/news/europe/2022/10/22/test-news-title I get a 404

Comment: but if I go to domain.com/english/test-news-title I get a page but no results because the entire slug is world/news/europe/2022/10/22/test-news-title saved like this to make it more dynamic and with dates

Comment: this solved it, RewriteRule ^en/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /en/news.php?id=$1  [L] does it looks correct ?